# Is there a way to create an int[] that has the dynamic capabilities of an ArrayList? (Size distribution of particles)

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to implement a method that returns an array containing size distribution of particles (where the size of a particle is amount of pixels). What I've tried is using and int[] and set it to different lengths to try to match the max/min size of the particles. I quickly got to the conclusion that this was not the way to go since the sizes vary alot. What i basically need is an int[] that is dynamic in size.

What I've tried so far:

The map has labels(Integer) for each particle (list of pixels)

```
private int[] particleSizeDistribution(Map<Integer, List<Pixel>> particleMap) {
        int[] particleSizeDistribution = new int[tried many different lengths here :)];

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Pixel>> entry : particleMap.entrySet()) {
            particleSizeDistribution[entry.getValue().size()] += 1;  
        }
        return particleSizeDistribution;
    }
```

The particles are generated from a series of images from a microscope. The problem with using an int[] is that i need to pick a fixed length. One experiment might show particles in the range of 20-200 pixels and the next 100-1500.

I know that ArrayLists are dynamic, and I tried using it but what if the first particle is 125 pixels in size(meaning +1 at index 125) and the list is empty? Didn't work when I tried.

Hope someone can get me in the right direction!

Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Why not use a [`Map<Integer, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: `particleMap.entrySet().stream(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size())))`

Comment: So you're trying to create a histogram of sizes? You can iterate through your `map.values()` one time to get the maximum size, and use that to create your int[]. Then your loop should work. The map suggestions will be something of a sparse represntation. After you create it you can create your int[] to contain the values.

Comment: Why do you say `The problem with using an int[] is that i need to pick a fixed length.`? You refer to the initialization inside your method, or is it a requirement to the function to always return same-size arrays? Because here in the comments are already lots of good answers. Why have the function return and int[] anyway? Problem with the int[] is that it will be sparse, unnecessary big, and slow to check. (Where would you keep track of maximum?). So I'd also suggest rethinking that design choice and lean towards a TreeMap or PriorityQueue or Heap Map, if you need some sort of ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the tips everyone!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, it may be better to remap existing map into `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key will be the size of `List<Pixel>` using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.summingInt`:

```java
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> particleSizeMap = particleMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getValue().size(), 
            TreeMap::new, // sort by the particle list size
            Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)
        ));
```

Then the sorted map may be used to build an array:

```java
int[] particleSizeDistribution = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, particleSizeMap.lastKey())
        .map(i -> particleSizeMap.getOrDefault(i, 0))
        .toArray();
```